# What is the Travis CI config for a repository that has multiple folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, yaml, travis-ci

I have a repository that has 2 subfolders and in each subfolder is a different app. I want to make a `.travis.yml` config that goes in each subfolders and does the following:

- `cd subfolder1`
- `npm install`
- `npm test`
- `npm run build`

And do the same thing for the second folder

- `cd subfolder2`
- `npm install`
- `npm test`
- `npm run build`

I could not find anything regarding to this setup. Can someone please help me?
Any idea will be greatly appreciated!

This is my current config setup only for one subfolder:

```
before_install
- cd subfolder 1
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "stable"
cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/.npm"
script:
  - npm test
  - npm run build
on:
  branch: master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading @tbking's answer I came up with a config file that works pretty well.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "stable"
cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/.npm"
matrix:
  fast_finish: true
  include:
    - env: ECMAScript
      before_script:
        - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/templates/ECMAScript
        - npm install
      script:
        - npm test
        - npm run build
    - env: TypeScript
      before_script:
        - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/templates/TypeScript
        - npm install
      script:
        - npm test
        - npm run build
on:
  branch: master
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add all these steps to a lifecycle hook like [before_install](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#installing-packages-on-standard-infrastructure).

```
before_install
  - cd ./subfolder1
  - npm install
  - npm test 
  - npm run build
  - cd ./subfolder2
  - npm install
  - npm test 
  - npm run build
```

You can also do the testing and building part of both these projects in `script` section, but the idea is that you need to manage yourself the sequence of actions performed. This will render `install` stage just a placeholder.